# Reordering DOM elements in given order

Tags: javascript

I've got a set of divs with a certain class that needs to be reordered in a specific order. This order is determined by an array. For example, the order of the divs needs to be `[14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`.

The issue I'm having is that if the numbers are not in sequence, or if the order is not in sequence the divs do not order the way I want them. I feel like it's something small I'm missing.

```js
var parents = document.getElementsByClassName('parent');

for (var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
  reorder(parents[i]);
}

function reorder(container) {
  var order = [14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
  var tempList = [];
  var children = container.getElementsByClassName('child');

  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    tempList[i] = children[i];
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {

    container.appendChild(tempList[order[i] - 1]);
  }
}
```

```css
.red {
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-top:1px solid red;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent green">
  <div class="child-other">This</div>
  <div class="other-class">Doesn't</div>
  <div class="other-class">Work</div>
  
  <div class="child">8</div>
  <div class="child">9</div>
  <div class="child">10</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
  <div class="child">11</div>
  <div class="child">12</div>
  <div class="child">13</div>
  <div class="child">14</div>
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
</div>

<div class="parent red">
  <div class="child-other">This</div>
  <div class="other-class">Works</div>
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
  <div class="child">8</div>
  <div class="child">9</div>
  <div class="child">10</div>
  <div class="child">11</div>
  <div class="child">12</div>
  <div class="child">13</div>
  <div class="child">14</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There problem is you are not comparing content of child `DIV` with `order` array. Please find below working solution

```js
var parents = document.getElementsByClassName('parent');
for (var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
  reorder(parents[i]);
}

function findElement(num, collection) {
  var child = null
  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    if (collection[i].innerHTML.trim() == num) {
      child = collection[i];
    }
  }
  return child;
}

function reorder(container) {
  var order = [14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
  var tempList = [];
  var children = container.getElementsByClassName('child');
  for (var i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
    container.append(findElement(order[i], children))
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent green">
  <div class="child-other">This</div>
  <div class="other-class">Doesn't</div>
  <div class="other-class">Work</div>

  <div class="child">8</div>
  <div class="child">9</div>
  <div class="child">10</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
  <div class="child">11</div>
  <div class="child">12</div>
  <div class="child">13</div>
  <div class="child">14</div>
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
</div>

<div class="parent red">
  <div class="child-other">This</div>
  <div class="other-class">Works</div>
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
  <div class="child">8</div>
  <div class="child">9</div>
  <div class="child">10</div>
  <div class="child">11</div>
  <div class="child">12</div>
  <div class="child">13</div>
  <div class="child">14</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the content doesn't matter in this case. It's there as a placeholder.

Comment: So you just want to order them as per their index?

Comment: then, i guess it is already working as expected. Can you add expected output?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery selects elements by the DOM order. And your logic appends your elements to the `container` by picking from the order the JQuery selects them.

So, when the number in the `div` doesn't correspond to the order the elements are selected, you won't get the expected results.

Although this design doesn't look so good to me, your easiest way out seems to be sorting the DOM selection before appending them.

```
tempList.sort(function(a,b){
    a = a.html();
    b = b.html();

    return a > b;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is comparing each value from order array against the `innerHTML` of the tempList elements.

```js
var parents = document.getElementsByClassName('parent');

for (var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
  reorder(parents[i]);
}

function reorder(container) {
  var order = [14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
  var children = container.getElementsByClassName('child');
  var tempList = Array.from(container.getElementsByClassName('child'));
  for (var i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
    container.appendChild(tempList.find((el) => { return el.innerHTML == order[i]   }));
  }
}
```

```css
.red {
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-top:1px solid red;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent green">
  <div class="child-other">This</div>
  <div class="other-class">Doesn't</div>
  <div class="other-class">Work</div>
  
  <div class="child">8</div>
  <div class="child">9</div>
  <div class="child">10</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
  <div class="child">11</div>
  <div class="child">12</div>
  <div class="child">13</div>
  <div class="child">14</div>
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
</div>

<div class="parent red">
  <div class="child-other">This</div>
  <div class="other-class">Works</div>
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
  <div class="child">8</div>
  <div class="child">9</div>
  <div class="child">10</div>
  <div class="child">11</div>
  <div class="child">12</div>
  <div class="child">13</div>
  <div class="child">14</div>
</div>
```